# How to effectively mute windows media player?

Tags: vb.net, audio, axwindowsmediaplayer

I am creating a system that uses windows media player. Actually this system doesn't need to have sounds at all so how can I mute my windows media player throughout the entire runtime?

Answer (score 0):

Basically the first you might want to try is to put `mute` in the `OnLoad Event` of your form

```
    frmQueuing.AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.settings.mute = True
```

But if it doesn't work you can try setting the volume of windows media player to `0` in the Onload Event of your form.

```
    frmQueuing.AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.settings.volume = 0
```

Comment: Because I want to format it in a question and answer format? :)

Answer (score 0):

the things to do is to make a mediaplayer volume off but you need to turn off volume of media Load from source 
example that code turn off volume from load playlist

```
` Private Sub playlist_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Form1.AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.settings.volume = 0

    End Sub
```

`

also following code turn off volume from form1 load window

```
 `Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.settings.volume = 0


    End Sub `
```