# How to create a mute button on c# windows form

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, windows-forms-designer, windows-media-player

everyone, I'm working in a project of my university and I have a problem, music is played on my project using the library "Media", with whis library I can play the song or stop it, but I want to have a mute button where I can mute the song if I want and vice versa, can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you please show your existing code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32732578/how-to-effectively-mute-windows-media-player

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154089/mute-windows-volume-using-c-sharp

Comment: Do you want to use the control `windows media playe`r to complete that operation? Or simply want to turn off the sound of the system? What method do you currently use to play music? The` soundPlayer` in Media can only play `.wav` files, and there is no way to set the volume.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.